# TEdit and TCheckBox Validations

Tags: edit, c++builder, tcheckbox

My purpose is that the users will never be able to check a `TCheckBox` when the number is entered into a `TEdit` less than 7 digits. Also, this `TCheckBox` can never be checked when the `TEdit` is being empty.

A problem of my codes is sometimes `TCheckBox` can still be checked although `TEdit` is being empty.

Moreover, my another target is that the start button can never be executed or will always display an error message if the start button is clicked when the TCheckBox is checked while the `TEdit` is being empty.

The problem is what codes should I put in the start button ?.

I am using the following code:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm::MyTEditBoxKeyPress(TObject *Sender, System::WideChar &Key)
{
    if( Key == VK_BACK ) return;
    if((Key < '1') || (Key > '9'))
    {
        MessageDlg("Please enter number only.",mtInformation, TMsgDlgButtons()<< mbOK, 0);
        Key = 0;
    }
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm::MyTEditBoxExit(TObject *Sender)
{
    if (MyTEditBox->Text.Length() < 7) {
        MessageDlg("Please enter at least 7 digit.",mtInformation, TMsgDlgButtons()<< mbOK, 0);
    }
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm::MyCheckBoxClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    if (MyCheckBox->Tag == 0 ) {
        MyCheckBox->Tag = 1;
        if (MyTEditBox->Text.Length() >= 7)
            MyCheckBox->Checked = true;
        IdThrottler->BitsPerSec = StrToInt64(MyTEditBox->Text);
    }
    else {
        MyCheckBox->Tag = 0;
        if (MessageDlg("Please enter at least 7 digit.",mtInformation, TMsgDlgButtons()<< mbOK, 0) == mrYes)
            MyCheckBox->Checked = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `Checked` instead of the `Tag` in the checkbox click function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the throttler's `BitsPerSec` property is an `int`, not an `__int64`, so you should be using `StrtoInt()` instead of `StrToInt64()`.

You are setting the `TCheckBox::Enabled` property in the `TCheckBox::OnClick` event, so the user has to actually click on the `TCheckBox` to make it update itself.  If the user only typed in the `TEdit` and never clicks on the `TCheckBox`, it will never be updated.

If you don't want the user to click on the `TCheckBox` at all unless the `TEdit` text is adequate, you should use the `TEdit::OnChange` event to set the `TCheckBox::Enabled` property, and get rid of your `TCheckBox::Tag` handling altogether:

```
void __fastcall TMyForm::MyTEditBoxChange(TObject *Sender)
{
    MyCheckBox->Enabled = (MyTEditBox->GetTextLen() >= 7);
}

void __fastcall TMyForm::MyCheckBoxClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    if (MyCheckBox->Checked)
        IdThrottler->BitsPerSec = StrToInt(MyTEditBox->Text);
    else
        IdThrottler->BitsPerSec = 0;
}
```

Do note that just because the user can type in more than 6 digits does not mean its `Text` represents a value `int` value.  In that situation, `StrToInt()` will raise an exception.

A different way to handle this is to add a `TActionList` to your Form, create a custom action in it, assign that action to the `TCheckBox::Action` property, and then use the `TAction::OnUpdate` event to set the `TAction::Enabled` property (which will enable/disable the `TCheckBox`):

```
void __fastcall TMyForm::MyActionUpdate(TObject *Sender)
{
    MyAction1->Enabled = (MyTEditBox->GetTextLen() >= 7);
}
```

The benefit of this approach is that the `TCheckBox::Enabled` property will be updated automatically and in real-time without having to manually react to changes in the `TEdit` at all.

With that said, if you are using a modern version of C++Builder, `TEdit` has a `NumbersOnly` property.  When set to true, you don't have to filter keystrokes in the `TEdit::OnKeyPress` event anymore, the OS will prevent the user from typing non-digit characters for you (besides, when you are filtering manually, you are not allowing the user to type in `0` digits, which is wrong).

If you really must allow the user to enter a number via a `TEdit`, and if the `TEdit::NumbersOnly` property is not available in your version of C++Builder, you still have a couple of other options (which you should consider anyway, even in modern C++Builder versions):

1. make the `TEdit` read-only, attach a `TUpDown` to it via the `TUpDown::Associate` property, and assign appropriate `TUpDown::Min` and `TUpDown::Max` values as needed.  Use the `TUpDown::Position` property to update the throttler's `BitsPerSec` property:

   ```
   void __fastcall TMyForm::MyActionUpdate(TObject *Sender)
   {
       MyAction1->Enabled = (MyUpDown->Position > 999999);
   }

   void __fastcall TMyForm::MyUpDownClick(TObject *Sender, TUDBtnType Button)
   {
       if ((MyCheckBox->Enabled) && (MyCheckBox->Checked))
           IdThrottler->BitsPerSec = MyUpDown->Position;
       else
           IdThrottler->BitsPerSec = 0;
   }
   ```

   Maybe also use a `TTrackBar` that sets the `TUpDown::Value` property in larger increments so the user does not have to press the up/down arrows for more than small adjustments:

   ```
   void __fastcall TMyForm::MyTrackBarChange(TObject *Sender)
   {
       MyUpDown->Position = MyTrackBar->Position;
       MyUpDownClick(NULL, btNext);
   }
   ```
2. Don't bother using a `TEdit` at all.  Use a `TCSpinEdit` or `TSpinEdit` instead (depending on your version of C++Builder).  The user can type in numbers, and it will reject non-numeric input.  It provides up/down arrows, like `TUpDown`, for making small adjustments. And it has a `Value` property that returns/accepts an `int` instead of a `String`, just like the `TUpDown::Position` property.

   ```
   void __fastcall TMyForm::MyActionUpdate(TObject *Sender)
   {
       MyAction1->Enabled = (MySpinEdit->Value > 999999);
   }

   void __fastcall TMyForm::MySpinEditChange(TObject *Sender)
   {
       if ((MyCheckBox->Enabled) && (MyCheckBox->Checked))
           IdThrottler->BitsPerSec = MySpinEdit->Value;
       else
           IdThrottler->BitsPerSec = 0;
   }
   ```

Either way, the user cannot enter non-numeric values at all, and the `TCheckBox` still auto-disables itself for values that are smaller than your desired threshold.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Remy. All your answers is very valuable to me, as well as has improved my programming knowledge. Sure, your coding skills is really great :). Anyway, can you teach me how to convert the `IdThrottler's Bits` to `KB/sec` so that I can apply the style of IDM's [speed limiter](http://s13.postimg.org/njmsudgl3/Screenshot_1.png) ?
‎

Comment: There are 8 bits in a byte, and 1024 bytes in a KB. Basic math. If you wanted to limit the speed to 50 KB/sec, for example, you would set `BitsPerSec` to (8 * 1024 * 50) = 409600 bits.

Comment: I know about that, But what I meant is that the speed value is entered into `TSpinEdit` or `TEdit` is in `kilobytes` and not `bits`. Do you have an additional `TiDHTTP` function for it? Or do you have a plan to update `TiDHTTP` so that it will has an option in `BytesPerSec` instead of `BitsPerSec`  ?.